# Where do executables look for shared objects at runtime?

Tags: compiling, executable, path, dynamic-linking

I understand how to define include shared objects at linking/compile time. However, I still wonder how do executables look for the shared object (`*.so` libraries) at execution time.

For instance, my app `a.out` calls functions defined in the `lib.so` library. After compiling, I move `lib.so` to a new directory in my `$HOME`.

How can I tell `a.out` to go look for it there?

Comment: A quick solution is to use g++ -Wl,-R. this will force loader to look into the current folder for so libraries. Or -Wl,-R$HOME/path to specidy some other fixed folder.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

The [shared library HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) explains most of the mechanisms involved, and the [dynamic loader manual](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) goes into more detail. Each unix variant has its own way, but most use the same executable format ([ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)) and have similar [dynamic linkers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker)¹ (derived from Solaris). Below I'll summarize the common behavior with a focus on Linux; check your system's manuals for the complete story.

(Terminology note: the part of the system that loads shared libraries is often called “dynamic linker”, but sometimes “dynamic loader” to be more precise. “Dynamic linker” can also mean the tool that generates instructions for the dynamic loader when compiling a program, or the combination of the compile-time tool and the run-time loader. In this answer, “linker” refers to the run-time part.)

In a nutshell, when it's looking for a dynamic library (`.so` file) the linker tries:

- directories listed in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable (`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` on OSX);
- directories listed in the executable's [rpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath);
- directories on the system search path, which (on Linux at least) consists of the entries in `/etc/ld.so.conf` plus `/lib` and `/usr/lib`.

The rpath is stored in the executable (it's the `DT_RPATH` or `DT_RUNPATH` dynamic attribute). It can contain absolute paths or paths starting with `$ORIGIN` to indicate a path relative to the location of the executable (e.g. if the executable is in `/opt/myapp/bin` and its rpath is `$ORIGIN/../lib:$ORIGIN/../plugins` then the dynamic linker will look in `/opt/myapp/lib` and `/opt/myapp/plugins`). The rpath is normally determined when the executable is compiled, with the `-rpath` option to `ld`, but you can change it afterwards with [`chrpath`](ftp://ftp.hungry.com/pub/hungry/chrpath/).

In the scenario you describe, if you're the developer or packager of the application and intend for it to be installed in a `…/bin`, `…/lib` structure, then link with `-rpath='$ORIGIN/../lib'`. If you're installing a pre-built binary on your system, either put the library in a directory on the search path (`/usr/local/lib` if you're the system administrator, otherwise a directory that you add to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`), or try `chrpath`.

Comment: On some systems, `/lib64` and `/usr/lib64` are used for 64 bit binaries and `/lib` and `/usr/lib` are used for 32 bit binaries.

Comment: Why does not this *right* answer talk anything about *ldconfig* ??

Comment: @LovesProbability Because the question was about where executables look for libraries, which doesn't involve `ldconfig`. `ldconfig` gets involved when you install a library.

Comment: Note that the "system search path" for `*.so` libraries is _not_ the same as `$PATH`. The search path is as given by @enzotib in their answer. To print out the paths that will be searched, run `ldconfig -v 2>/dev/null | grep -v ^$'\t'`.

Comment: for me, to run ldconfig, I needed `/sbin/ldconfig` and that other magic of Andrew Bate to get it to run non-root

Comment: Instead of "the linker tries" you probably want to say "the loader tries", aren't you?

Comment: @meolic They're the same thing in this context, but I can see how switching terms is confusing, so I've added a note.

Comment: There's an important difference between the `DT_RPATH` and `DT_RUNPATH`, explained in the `ld.so(8)` manpage. While new versions of `ld` default the `--enable-new-dtags` (which sets `DT_RUNPATH`), people still run older binaries, and glossing over the difference (as this answer does) still has the potential of wasting their time.

Comment: Also, `$ORIGIN` and other interpolations are not supported on systems like OpenBSD.

Answer (score 26):

In Linux the behavior is explicited in the `ld(1)` man page

> ```
>        The linker uses the following search paths to locate required
>        shared libraries:
>
>        1.  Any directories specified by -rpath-link options.
>
>        2.  Any directories specified by -rpath options.  The difference
>            between -rpath and -rpath-link is that directories specified by
>            -rpath options are included in the executable and used at
>            runtime, whereas the -rpath-link option is only effective at
>            link time. Searching -rpath in this way is only supported by
>            native linkers and cross linkers which have been configured
>            with the --with-sysroot option.
>
>        3.  On an ELF system, for native linkers, if the -rpath and
>            -rpath-link options were not used, search the contents of the
>            environment variable "LD_RUN_PATH".
>
>        4.  On SunOS, if the -rpath option was not used, search any
>            directories specified using -L options.
>
>        5.  For a native linker, the search the contents of the environment
>            variable "LD_LIBRARY_PATH".
>
>        6.  For a native ELF linker, the directories in "DT_RUNPATH" or
>            "DT_RPATH" of a shared library are searched for shared
>            libraries needed by it. The "DT_RPATH" entries are ignored if
>            "DT_RUNPATH" entries exist.
>
>        7.  The default directories, normally /lib and /usr/lib.
>
>        8.  For a native linker on an ELF system, if the file
>            /etc/ld.so.conf exists, the list of directories found in that
>            file.
>
>        If the required shared library is not found, the linker will issue
>        a warning and continue with the link.
> ```

Comment: "The default directories, normally /lib and /usr/lib." -> how can I find out if my system is normal?

Comment: The question is about runtime and not link time

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure the answer here is `ldconfig`.

> ldconfig creates the necessary links and cache to the most recent shared libraries found in the directories specified on the command line, in the file /etc/ld.so.conf, and in the trusted directories (/lib and /usr/lib). The cache is used by the run-time linker, ld.so or ld-linux.so. ldconfig checks the header and filenames of the libraries it encounters when determining which versions should have their links updated.

http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig

Answer (score 2):

For running applications the file `/proc/1234/maps` contains all actual dynamically linked libraries.

Where `1234` is the pid of the running executable.

Linux follows LD_LIBRARY_PATH and other variables, as pointed out in answer by Gilles.

Comment: It is nice that you confirm in your second sentence that Gilles answer helps. The first part however doesn't contribute at all to explaining how to tell a.out where the files are, only where the were gotten from if they are already found. All in all this should just be a comment, not an answer.