# Error while loading shared libraries

Tags: gentoo, c, dynamic-linking, linker

My project tree looks something like that:

```
src/
include/
Makefile
lib/
   lib/3rdparylib/
```

I didn't code `3rdpartylib`, but decided to embed its source code in my project packaging. I compile the software by doing the following steps:

```
$ cd lib/3rdpartylib/
$ make
$ ln -s 3rdpartylib.so.0 3rdpartylib.so
```

Then I compile each of **my** source files like this:

```
$ gcc -c src/file.c -I include -o file.o -l 3rdparylib -L lib/3rdpartylib -I lib/3rdpartylib/include
```

Then I link:

```
$ gcc file1.o file2.o -l3rdpartylib -L lib/3rdpartylib -o myapp
```

When I am on my main machine, it works perfectly.
Today I tried to launch it on another machine. It compiled and linked without any problem. However when I tried to launch the application I got the following error message.

./myapp: error while loading shared libraries: 3rdpartylib.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried doing the following:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/3rdpartylib.so
```

It seems to work. But I understand that using LD_LIBRARY_PATH is a bad practice. It bothers me to have this variable set up every time I want to run my app.

What am I missing? Why does it work on my main machine (where LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set to anything) and not on the other machine? Does it matter that the other machine is a virtual one?

If it is of any help, my main machine is a Debian box, and my "new" machine is a Sabayon (Gentoo), running in Virtualbox.

Comment: I don't see what's going on at the moment, but [this may provide useful background](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22926/where-do-executables-look-for-shared-objects-at-runtime).

Answer (score 4):

What matters is what Linux distribution each machine uses, because they handle library paths differently. On the Gentoo (Sabayon) machine, if you want a third party library to be usable system-wide, you should:

- Create a file under `/etc/env.d/` that will contain the additional environment setup. The files are named using the scheme `[0-9][0-9]somename` - the two initial digits decide on the order in which they are used. A good practice requires that your custom settings are added (near) *last*, so `99` is a proper beginning, as long as it works. **Getting to the point:** Create a file named like

  ```
  /etc/env.d/99mythirdpartylib
  ```

  containing

  ```
  LDPATH=/path/to/your/library
  ```
- To make the changes active without reboot, run as root:

  ```
  env-update && source /etc/profile
  ```

  (which will update the environment as well as run `ldconfig`).

[Reference](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=2&chap=5), if you'd like one.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to set a global library search path for your whole system with the `/etc/env.d` approach, you can either:

Just set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the **PATH** of your library (you did set it to the library itself, that won't work), the same which you set with the `-L` parameter to gcc e.g.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$PROJ/lib/3rdpartylib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

(the last part is for preserving the variable if it was already set, which it shouldn't be normally). 
*This will only work in you current shell and you will have to set it again everytime.*

Or you link using a 'static' library search paths like this:

```
gcc file1.o file2.o -L./lib/3rdpartylib -Wl,-rpath=./lib/3rdpartylib  -l3rdpartylib  -o myapp
```

`-Wl` specifies commmand line arguments that will not be processed by gcc but instead be passed to the linker.
*Since the library search path will be written into the binary, this will work even on different machines (provided the library exists)*

**PS:** Since you're just talking about the case where you're developing a project, I think this temporary way is more appropriate than putting it in system-wide configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
$ gcc file1.o file2.o -l3rdpartylib -L lib/3rdpartylib -o myapp
```

searches for a file called `lib3rdpartylib.so` in your library path, which doesn't even include `lib/3rdpartylib`! If you look at the gcc man page, it states that when specifying a library path with `-L` it must come before the `-l` flags, or it will not be searched. Really, the simplest solution is to just link to the library itself:

```
$ gcc file1.o file2.o lib/3rdpartylib/3rdpartylib.so -o myapp
```

That way, the library will be searched for in the library paths and dynamically loaded when `myapp` runs.

If you want to check it, just do an `strace -eopen ./myapp` once it's installed and look at where it tries to load the library from.

Comment: If that were the issue, wouldn't `ld` complain during building? The app is said to get built fine.

Answer (score -1):

You have to tell your system where to look for libraries. This job is done by `/etc/ld.so.cache`. You can add libraries or whole directories in `/etc/ld.so.conf`.

You can rebuild the cache by doing:

```
# /sbin/ldconfig -v
```

Comment: On Gentoo this is **not** the way to do it: the top line of `/etc/ld.so.conf` proves it vividly, saying ***"ld.so.conf autogenerated by env-update; make all changes to contents of /etc/env.d directory"***

Comment: ...And `/etc/env.d` is sourced on *each boot*, so you'd loose all your changes.

Comment: Ok I don't know Gentoo, `env-update` will do exactly what I say : `env-update will also extract the information from the LDPATH variable and use that to create /etc/ld.so.conf. After this, it will run ldconfig to recreate the /etc/ld.so.cache`. So your answer is better ;-)