# Install a program downloaded as .tar file

Tags: linux, linux-mint, software-installation

I'm a new linux user running Mint 17.3.  I want to install a program I downloaded as a .tar file.  I extracted the contents of the .tar.  Now I see folders:

```
programname/lib
programname/bin
programname/include
```

There are files in those folders but nothing that looks like an install file.  I'm not sure where to go from here to install this program.  Any help would be great.

Comment: You're probably going to need to include more information than that, e.g. what the program is that you're trying to install. The fact that you downloaded the software as a TAR file probably isn't going to have a whole lot to do with the installation process.

Comment: the software is SmartCash wallet https://smartcash.cc/wallets/

Comment: In this case, just copy the files to system folder. copy bin to /usr/bin, lib to /lib

Comment: ok so I copy the contents of the bin folder to /usr/bin and contents of the lib folder to /usr/lib ?  or just /lib ?

Comment: both /usr/lib and /lib works, Linux will find the file anyway

Comment: Ok done.  now how do I actually run the program?

Comment: @firsttube Did you read my solution?

Comment: @igal yes, thank you very much that was helpful.

Comment: @firsttube If it resolved your question, could please accept it as an answer? Otherwise, could you tell me what's still missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short Answer

It looks like your download has a collection of precompiled files. In order to "install" them you'll just need to copy or move each file to an appropriate location.

In this case you'll probably just want to copy all of the files from each subdirectory of `smartcash-1.0.0` to the corresponding subirectory of `/usr/local`, e.g.:

```bsh
cp -i smartcash-1.0.0/bin/* /usr/local/bin
cp -i smartcash-1.0.0/include/* /usr/local/include
cp -i smartcash-1.0.0/lib/* /usr/local/lib
```

That's it. Once you do that you should be able to run four new commands:

```
smartcash-cli
smartcash-qt
smartcash-tx
smartcashd
```

---

### Long Answer

Here is what I did to try to figure out what you're dealing with. First I downloaded the TAR archive:

```bsh
wget 'https://smartcash.cc/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/smartcash-1.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz'
```

Then I decompressed the archive:

```bsh
tar xzf smartcash-1.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz
```

Then I viewed the resulting directory:

```bsh
tree smartcash-1.0.0
```

Here is the output from `tree`:

```
smartcash-1.0.0
|-- bin
|   |-- smartcash-cli
|   |-- smartcash-qt
|   |-- smartcash-tx
|   `-- smartcashd
|-- include
|   `-- bitcoinconsensus.h
`-- lib
    |-- libbitcoinconsensus.so -> libbitcoinconsensus.so.0.0.0
    |-- libbitcoinconsensus.so.0 -> libbitcoinconsensus.so.0.0.0
    `-- libbitcoinconsensus.so.0.0.0
```

It looks what we have are some precompiled executable programs (in the 'bin/' subdirectory), some shared libraries (in the `lib/` subdirectory), and a header file (in the `include` subdirectory).

In general, you probably want to put executables into a directory that's in your path. To see the directories in your PATH you can run the following command:

```bsh
(IFS=:; for path in ${PATH[@]}; do echo "${path}"; done)
```

Here is what the output might look like:

```
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
```

A typical place to put these would be `/usr/local/bin`. You could that with a command such as the following:

```bsh
cp -i smartcash-1.0.0/bin/* /usr/local/bin
```

The shared library files should go in a directory that's in your shared-library search-path. To see what your shared-library search-path is you should check the `/etc/ld.so.conf` configuration file. Here's what's in mine:

```
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

So it's including configuration files from the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` directory. Checking the contents of that directory (i.e. `cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*`) reveals the following list of directories:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot
/usr/local/lib
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

So I would put the files in the `/usr/local/lib` directory, e.g.:

```bsh
cp -i smartcash-1.0.0/lib/* /usr/local/lib
```

For further discussion on the subject of where to put shared libraries you might want to refer to the following posts:

- [Where do executables look for shared objects at runtime?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22926/where-do-executables-look-for-shared-objects-at-runtime)
- [Is /usr/local/lib searched for shared libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743233/is-usr-local-lib-searched-for-shared-libraries)

Finally, you'll probably want to put the header file in `/usr/local/include` - for the sake of consistency, e.g.:

```bsh
cp -i smartcash-1.0.0/include/* /usr/local/include
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tar -C /usr/local --strip-components 1 -xf xxx.tar.xz
```

Answer (score 0):

Packages not installed via your distro belong in `/opt`. So:

```
sudo bash  # or sudo each command
cd /tmp
tar xvf progname.tar
# use atool's aunpack to guard against tar-bombs
mkdir /opt
mv progname/ opt/
```

Then, symlink the executables:

```
ln -s /opt/progname/bin/* /usr/local/bin
ln -s /opt/progname/lib/* /usr/local/lib
ln -s /opt/progname/include/* /usr/local/include
```