# Is it safe to delete library source directory after library install?

Tags: software-installation, libraries

I've downloaded some library archived source files, extracted it in `some-library` directory, and then installed it with standard Autotools procedure as specified by library `README` file:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Is it now safe to delete `some-library` directory because library files are installed in the [default directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22926/where-do-executables-look-for-shared-objects-at-runtime) unless otherwise specified?

Comment: Yes, it is safe to delete the sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, after you compiled the libraries and installed the produced binary files to their destination directories, you can safely delete the source directory. Please note however that sometimes it is still handy to keep them around as they may contain additional documentation or usage examples - and there are occasions when you might have to recompile them.